# Find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})\ln(1+\frac{1}{2n})\ln(1+\frac{1}{2n+1})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Here is another problem from IMC competition. Solution given there: [solutions](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2011/imc2011-day2-solutions.pdf), is totally taken out of blue for me. What is more I discovered the relationship $\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})=\ln(1+\frac{1}{2n})+\ln(1+\frac{1}{2n+1})$ used in the solution myslef yet wasn't able to find the solution to the problem. I would welcom your approache to the problem or some explanation how to come up with the idea and identity involving $g$ in the link.

Comment: Is it so strange that $$\frac{n+1}{n}=\frac{2n+1}{2n}\cdot\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}$$ ?

Comment: I didn't mean that it is a great observation. I said that in order to point out that even being aware of that I wasn't able to come up with solution presented ;)

Comment: @J.E.M.S The solution looks quite straightforward, but does use a "trick" to facilitate the development.  So, without the inspiration or experience with such techniques, it is not at all surprising that solution poses a formidable challenge.  Don't despair.  If the solution were easy, it likely wouldn't be in the IMC competition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact use this well known

if $a+b+c=0$,then we have
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$$

let $$a=-\ln{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)},b=-\ln{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\right)},c=\ln{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}$$

Comment: You are so right !